# In an audio mixer, when is it necessary to match the input impedance of other devices?

Tags: audio, mixer

I found an [audio mixer design](https://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/mixer1-1024x806.png) that introduces a 47k resistor on each input.

[image: Audio mixer schematic with pre-amps]

Credit: [Graham Lambert](https://www.circuitbasics.com/what-are-audio-mixers/)

According to the designer:

> We want the input impedance presented to each input to be constant and not a function of the gain setting. So here, the input impedance will be 47k to match most audio sources and dynamic microphones.

> LM324 op-amps U1.1, U1.2, and U1.3 are the input pre-amplifiers. Their function is to provide a suitable input impedance to the microphones and this is set to 47k by resistors R2, R4, and R7.

It seems that the pre-amps are added to compensate for the 50k resistors (which resistors are apparently used for impedance matching), but I'm not sure why you would want to impedance match. Relative to ground, I noticed that the input on my desktop speakers have a resistance of 50k, is this relevant? My input source (computer) has resistance of only 5k.

This raises the question, how necessary is it to have 50k on the inputs? The article seems to reference microphones a lot, so perhaps this is the reason?

Studying a much [simpler mixer circuit](https://sound-au.com/articles/audmix-f4.gif), the input resistors have lower values (10k to 20k depending on the pot K), as well as having no pre-amps on the inputs.

Are the pre-amps in the more complex circuit really necessary?

[image: Simple active audio mixer schematic]

Credit: [Rod Elliott](https://sound-au.com/articles/audio-mixing.htm)

Comment: I think the word "match" used in your quote is misleading. For audio (other than telephony) input impedances ought to be at least ten times higher than the output impedance of the source device that plugs into the input.

Comment: @Andyaka Are you you referring to the following? "So here, the input impedance will be 47k to match most audio sources and dynamic microphones."

Comment: Yes I am NickBolton

Comment: Use opamps rated and recommended for audio preamps. The lousy old LM324 is NEVER used for audio because they produce noise (hiss), awful crossover distortion and have such a low slew rate that high level frequencies above only 2lHz are cutoff.

Comment: @Audioguru Totally agree, I have noticed this with the LM324, the noise it adds is nasty. When searching for best audio opamp, the OPA167x seems to be the most popular low-noise audio opamp.

Answer (score 3):

The preamps are not there to compensate for input impedance, they are for amplifying the input signal, as for mics you likely need amplification anyway, so it makes most sense to input each signal separately and buffer with adjustable amplification, and use the buffered and amplified signals for summing.

And in audio the impedances are not matched, at least not any more even if they used to be. The point is that a source output has much smaller impedance than sink input, in order to have as much of the voltage signal at input. Anything from 20k to 100k would be a typical input for standard line level audio signals and this 47k is no exception.

It is possible that the wording of matching the input impedance just means that it has been selected to just match what typical inputs have and what typical sources expect, so it is just suitable and matches the environment. And so it does not mean a 47k input impedance is required to match with 47k source impedance.

Compared to the other mixer circuit, the input impedance will be lower and will depend on the potentiometer setting.

Comment: Use opamp rated and recommended for audio preamps.

Answer (score 2):

Impedance matching in audio mixer input means today in most cases  that the input doesn't load the signal source too much so that the signal voltage drops too low due the internal series impedance of the signal source. Typically the signal source has quite low impedance if it's an output of an electronic device which has active circuits. There can well be an intentionally inserted series resistor in the audio source output to prevent any harms caused by accidental short circuits which can occur easily when one connects or disconnects cables. That resistor might be for ex. 1 kOhm. It's effect to signal level is neglible when the audio mixer has input impedance tens of kilo-ohms.

Electric guitars, some vinyl record players and microphones really expect high enough audio mixer input impedance because they have high internal series impedance which even can contain capacitive or inductive components. Loading thenm too much by having too low audio mixer input impedance reduces the signal level and can cause unwanted frequency dependent filtering effects - for ex. kill the bass or trebles.

There's one exception where audio mixer input impedance and source impedance matching matching in the old sense i.e. the impedances must be close each other to minimize signal power losses - is important. That's low noise recording of weak sounds. There's no practical harm if one loses some audio signal power when he records say a loud drum , screaming singer or a horn with a close mic. But when one tries to record say acoustic guitar or silent human speech even at 2 meters the signal power loss caused by mismatch can be fatal. Cranking up the gain in the mixer lifts up also the noise.

In practice one must use a specially designed mic preamp to get high enough signal level with low enough noise. Only high end audio mixers have then already present in the desk mic inputs. Such preamp is designed with proper noise, impedance  and level calculations which are farfarfar from trivial. The design is made for a certain mic type.

Say 50 years ago people had tube amplifiers in bands also for vocal amplification. Low impedance dynamic mics simply couldn't generate enough voltage to drive the high impedance input of the amp with high enough level. In that case one connected a matching transformer between the mic and amp which lifted the voltage to high enough. Essentially it converted the amp input to a matched low impedance load without causing much signal power loss, so the noise level did not jump, only the vocal signal became loud.

Audio transformers are still used for this purpose, but the wide variety of modern amp circuit solutions have made them less important for mic impedance matching- Audio transformers have been used and still are used also to generate galvanic isolation, but that's another story.